# extract map from vertex and return an array of maps via REST-API

Tags: list, rest, dictionary, neo4j, gremlin

I am trying to put all properties of a vertex in a map and add additional values to this map. Later, I want to return this map as a JSON response. In general I find the [REST-API](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/gremlin-plugin.html) of neo4j a bit verbose and I need the ID of a vertex among other values. Therefore, I decided to do this directly via a gremlin query.

The result should look like:

```
[ {"id": 1, "name": "Name1"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Name2"} ]
```

I managed to do this using the following gremlin script:

```
x = [];
g.v( 1 ).out.transform{
                     m = [:];
                     m.putAll( it.map() );
                     m.put( "id", it.id );
                     x.add( m )
                    }.iterate();
x
```

However, I ran into issues with this query with neo4j community 1.8.2 and 1.9M05.

a) neo4j 1.8.2 returns a JSONArray of Strings instead of a JSONArray of JSONObjects:

```
[ "{id: 1, name: Name1}", "{id: 2, name: Name2}" ]
```

b) neo4j 1.9M5 returns an exception:

```
{
  "message":"Invalid list type: map",
  "exception":"IllegalStateException",
  "stacktrace":
      [
        "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.RepresentationFormat.serializeList(RepresentationFormat.java:65)",
        "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.ListRepresentation.serialize(ListRepresentation.java:50)",
        "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat.assemble(OutputFormat.java:179)",
        "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat.formatRepresentation(OutputFormat.java:131)",
        "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat.response(OutputFormat.java:117)",
        "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat.ok(OutputFormat.java:55)",
        "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:122)",
        "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)"
      ]
}
```

If I modify the gremlin script and change x to a map, it works in both neo4j versions:

```
x = [:];
g.v( 1 ).out.transform{
                     m = [:];
                     m.putAll( it.map() );
                     m.put( "id", it.id );
                     x.put(it.id, m );
                    }.iterate();
x
```

returns

```
{ "1" : {"id": 1, "name": "Name1"}, "2" : {"id": 2, "name": "Name2"} }
```

the results, however, is now a JSONObject with JSONObjects in it.

Is there a way to solve my problem using gremlin? I just started learning gremlin two days ago.

Comment: This really isn't the answer to your problem as I don't know much about how Neo4j does REST serialization, but here's a tweak to make your Gremlin a bit more Gremliny: x=[];g.v(1).out.transform{m=[id:it.id];m.putAll(it.map());m}.fill(x)  This way you get rid of the side-effect in the transform of adding to list and the fill iterates your pipeline for you.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! Still getting used to gremlin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both cases are not functional because of neo4j. Version 1.8.2 has poor JSONSerialization when it comes to custom maps. A fix for Version 1.9 has been supplied.